# How to test php api in postman? json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

Tags: php, api, postman

I want to test my Php api in postman, please guide me,

Below code working fine and this php api code using for Android Retrofit but i want to test this api in postman.

```
<?php 
require 'db.php';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
if($data['mobile'] == ''  or $data['password'] == '')
{
    $returnArr = array("ResponseCode"=>"401","Result"=>"false","ResponseMsg"=>"Something Went Wrong!");
}
else
{
    $mobile = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data['mobile']));
    $password = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data['password']));
    
$chek = $con->query("select * from user where (mobile='".$mobile."' or email='".$mobile."') and status = 1 and password='".$password."'");
$status = $con->query("select * from user where status = 1");
if($status->num_rows !=0)
{
if($chek->num_rows != 0)
{
    $c = $con->query("select * from user where (mobile='".$mobile."' or email='".$mobile."')  and status = 1 and password='".$password."'");
    $c = $c->fetch_assoc();
    $returnArr = array("ResponseCode"=>"200","Result"=>"true","ResponseMsg"=>"Login successfully!");
}
else
{
    $returnArr = array("ResponseCode"=>"401","Result"=>"false","ResponseMsg"=>"Invalid Email/Mobile No or Password!!!");
}
}
else  
{
     $returnArr = array("ResponseCode"=>"401","Result"=>"false","ResponseMsg"=>"Your Status Deactivate!!!");
}
}

echo json_encode($returnArr);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In postmane first create new request.
- Then select POST as request and insert your localhost URL ( eg. http://localhost/project_folder_name/YOUR_FILE_NAME.php )
- In below tab select **Body**.
- In Body select **raw** to pass request data.
- Pass below json

`{ "mobile":"asdsad", "password":"asdasd" }`

- click send button you will get result

Atteached screen shot of postman request.[image]

List item